# Check if value from a dataframe column is in a list - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with customer data, and the customer name is in a column called "customer". I also have a list of "members". Some of the customers are also in the members list, but some are not. If the customer is a member, I want it to be TRUE, if not, then FALSE.

Here's what I have:

```
df[customer].isin([members])
```

but the error is telling me "unhashable type: 'list' ".

I've also tried:

```
df[customer] in [members]
```

and the error tells me "arrays were different lengths: 118816 vs 1171"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `df[customer].isin(members)` is the correct way, assuming elements of members are hashable.

Comment: those pesky brackets! this works. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra set of square brackets around `members` in your call to `df['customer'].isin()`.  Also, you don't have quotes around the column name `customer`. Your code should look like:

`df['customer'].isin(members)`